# AWS Lambda - Programmatically (javascript) get api gateway endpoint (with resource path) of another lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function (lambda-invoker) that invoke another lambda (my-lambda-function). Before making the invoke call, I need to know some information of my-lambda-function, in order to pass these informations in the payload of the invoke function (and then find them in the request event of my-lambda-function).
One of the informations I need to know is the full api gateway endpoint of my-lambda-function, something like:

```
https://YOUR-REST-API-ID.execute-api.YOUR-REGION.amazonaws.com/STAGE/RESOURCE-PATH
```

that is, with my function, something like this:

```
https://YOUR-REST-API-ID.execute-api.YOUR-REGION.amazonaws.com/test/my-lambda-function/info
```

What interest me is the 'stage/resource-path', so the '/test/my-lambda-function/info' part of the endpoint.

I know the function name of my-lambda-function, so I can get some information of this lambda calling the 'getFunction' api from aws sdk, but not the endpoint. I've searched in the sdk of the api gateway, and with that i can find the resource path, but I have to know the resource id (and I didi not find an sdk api that give me the resource id of my-lambda-function from the function name).

Someone know how to get the resource path of a lambda using aws sdk (for javascript in my case)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to use the function URL in order to invoke it.

It seems that [GetFunctionUrlConfigCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/getfunctionurlconfigcommand.html) is what you need.

You can provide the function name and you'll get the URL for it.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, thanks for the answer, but I think it is relate to the new URL feature that permit to attach an endpoint directly to the lambda, without using api gateway.
In my case I don't use this feature, I use ApiGateway (also for for authorizathion), and I need the endpoint url created by ApiGateway

Comment: Yep. It was an alternative solution in case you don't find one for finding the API Gateway trigger for your lambda